# WSL2 two separate Centos distributions have same eth0 inet address

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2, I want to run two separate instances of Centos 7, but when I do this both instances have the same eth0 inet address. Here's what I did...

I created a base Centos 7 tarball for my base, then created two separate distros and it all looks and runs as I expect it to look;

```
    > wsl --import centos7-1 centos7-1 centos7.tar.gz --version 2
    > wsl --import centos7-2 centos7-2 centos7.tar.gz --version 2
    > wsl -l -v
      NAME                   STATE           VERSION
    * centos7-1              Stopped         2
      centos7-2              Stopped         2
    > ls
        Directory: C:\Users\me\centos
    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                 -------------         ------ ----
    d-----          4/8/2022  11:28 AM                centos7-1
    d-----          4/8/2022  11:29 AM                centos7-2
    -a----          4/8/2022  11:24 AM      174323670 centos7.tar.gz
```

EXCEPT when I open and run each distro in separate PS windows, and run `ifconfig eth0` in each, they both show the same eth0 inet address.

So, what am I missing? How do I get them to have independent IP addresses?

I've noticed, since I first posted, that even instances of different linux distros, eg Ubuntu, run at the same time as Centos, all get the same IP address.

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here!  DanielB beat me to the "negative" answer, which is absolutely correct for why you see the same network in both instances.  However, I *might* have a solution for you -- Could you add your use-case for needing two separate addresses so that I can verify that my solution/workaround will cover it?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, a use case would be pre-commit testing of an n-tier or distributed system where I want to simulate `n` production assets as closely as possible before deploying my changes to actual assets shared by a distributed team. At this point, I don't have a solid need, I'm just kicking the tires.

Comment: That makes sense.  The good news is I have confirmed my hunch works -- The bad is that it isn't necessarily easy.  I'm working on getting the steps into a reproducible script, and I should have it posted at some point tomorrow.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I took this concept to work and was told it's too risky given a user could be 'root'.  er, not worth arguing.  Anyhow, with the ability to run a command `wsl ~ -d centos7-1 -u root -e sh -c "<some command> ; exit"` I don't see why you couldn't use PS scripts to bootstrap a default image, like Ubuntu, and use it to create arbitrary orchestration of other images with standard orchestration tools.  WSL seems to be way more resource friendly than Docker Desktop, so I do see a tangible benefit to this approach.

Comment: Well, since Docker Desktop (by default) just uses the same WSL2/Linux kernel features *anyway*, I'm not sure it's any more or less secure either way.  (Without knowing more about the project architecture), I'd see both techniques as sufficient only for, as you said, a dev/testing environment.  Production would still need to be on something more "robust".   On the other hand, it doesn't *seem* to me that Docker Desktop is all that much more resource-intensive, since it's still using a WSL2 session under the hood anyway.  With WSL2 and Docker, it's containers all the way down ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@DanielB's answer is an excellent explanation of why all WSL2 distributions (I like to call them "instances") share the same address.

Each WSL2 instance has a separate:

- PID namespace
- Mount namespace
- IPC namespace
- UTS namespace
- WSLg System Distribution

However, they all share the following with the parent WSL2 VM (and thus each other):

- User namespace
- (the only one we really care about here) Network namespace
- Cgroup namespace
- Device tree (other than `/dev/pts`)
- CPU/Kernel/Memory/Swap (obviously)
- `/init` binary (but not process)

The interesting thing is that we can use the same technology, namespaces, to "pretend" to create a separate IP address for each instance.

For the "n-tier testing" scenario you mention in the comments, this will hopefully be sufficient.  We can script the creation of the namespace for each instance and (optionally) automatically enter it via the `wsl` command-line.

While I had a hunch that this would work, I had never played around with network namespaces before trying this out.  Don't worry - It was a worthwhile learning exercise for me.  Huge credit goes to [this blog post](https://ops.tips/blog/using-network-namespaces-and-bridge-to-isolate-servers/) for getting me 90% there.

With that said, here's a first (or second, or third ...) pass at a script to configure a network namespace that will allow each namespace in each instance to have a different IP.

Create this as something like `/usr/local/sbin/wsl-netns.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
instance_num=$1
#if [ -e /run/netns/]

# Create the bridge that will be common to all instances.
# Only a `wsl --shutdown` will terminate the bridge, unless
# otherwise manually removed.
if [ ! -e /sys/devices/virtual/net/br1 ]
then
    ip link add name br1 type bridge
    ip addr add 10.0.0.253/24 brd + dev br1
    ip link set br1 up
fi

# Add namespace for this instance
if [ ! -e /run/netns/vnet${instance_num} ]
then
    ip netns add vnet${instance_num}
fi

# Adds a veth pair.  The vethX
# side will reside # inside the namespace 
# and be the primary NIC inside that namespace.
# The br-vethX  end will reside in the primary
# namespace.
ip link add veth${instance_num} type veth peer name br-veth${instance_num}
ip link set veth${instance_num} netns vnet${instance_num}
# Give it a unique IP based on the instance number
ip netns exec vnet${instance_num} \
    ip addr add 10.0.0.${instance_num}/24 dev veth${instance_num}
ip link set br-veth${instance_num} up
# Add the bridged end of the veth pair
# to br1
ip link set br-veth${instance_num} master br1
ip netns exec vnet${instance_num} \
    ip link set veth${instance_num} up

# Set the default route in the namespace
ip netns exec vnet${instance_num} \
    ip route add default via 10.0.0.253
# Enable loopback fort he namespace
ip netns exec vnet${instance_num} \
    ip link set up dev lo
# Set up NAT for return traffic
iptables \
    -t nat \
    -A POSTROUTING \
    -s 10.0.0.0/24 \
    -j MASQUERADE
# Enable forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Optional - Start a namespace for the 
# default WSL user (UID 1000).
# You can exit this namespace normally
# via the `exit` comamnd or Ctrl+D.
default_username=$(getent passwd 1000 | cut -d: -f1)
nsenter -n/var/run/netns/vnet${instance_num} su - $default_username
```

Not much error handling in there at the moment, but it's fairly straightforward.  Set it executable and run it from an instance with:

```
/usr/local/sbin/wsl-netns.sh 1 # replace with the instance number
```

Or start up WSL directly with it via:

```
wsl ~ -d centos7-1 -u root -e sh -c "/usr/local/sbin/wsl-netns.sh 1"
```

Just make sure to use a unique instance number for each.  The address for each instance/namespace will be `10.0.0.<instance_number>`, and you can access it from any other WSL2 instance.

To test, start a simple service inside one of the namespaces.  For example, if you are in the namespace that the script dropped you into, you could just run:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

You can then access that server at `10.0.0.1:8000` from another instance.  You will not be able to access the service via any other IP.

Alternatively, you don't have to use `nsenter` to drop into the namespace.  You can directly start a service inside it via:

```
sudo ip netns exec vnet<num> \
    service xyz start
```

Or whatever your bring-up command is.

Added bonus:

- IPv6 works since you aren't leaving internal WSL2 network.

Limitations:

- Tested in Ubuntu - May need small tweaks for CentOS.
- You cannot access those IP addresses from Windows, just other WSL2 instances.  You would need to add additional forwarding rules to handle that.
- Currently, all communication is via address.  If you want to assign hostnames, you'll need to override WSL's automatic `/etc/hosts` generation and define your own.  Or set it up via DNS, of course.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the work on this!  I ran a trial with this today, and I get an error `iptables v1.8.4 (nf_tables): Chain 'MASQUERADE' does not exist`.  Any ideas on that? Perhaps because iptables services are not started because it's a container not booted with init?

Comment: @CAB Hmm - Does iptables require a service on CentOS? (I'm seeing something about that in my Google search, at least).  That's not the case on Ubuntu.  Or it may have auto-started for me.  Let me dig deeper.  But if you can start your iptables-service on CentOS manually, that *might* resolve.

Comment: @CAB What's your kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: @CAB Forgot to mention -- I loaded up a CentOS 7 instance from Docker export, installed `iptables` and the command above worked for me.  Given the error message you got (and a Google search on my part), one possible cause is that the ip_masq isn't enabled in the kernel.  I was on a custom-built 5.10.93.2 kernel (from the Microsoft sources) when I wrote the answer yesterday, but I've since switched to the recently released stock 5.10.102.1 and it still works.  You may be able to obtain ther kernel update with a `wsl --update` if you aren't on it already.

Comment: 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2.  I started with Docker Centos, added some packages and made a tarball of the filesystem with `tar cvfzp centos7.tar.gz bin dev etc home lib lib64 media opt run root sbin srv usr var tmp`.  I'll redo with docker export, which sounds way easier anyway.

Comment: @CAB I see the problem - CentOS is using `iptables-nft`, which changes the syntax.  Are you sure you are on CentOS 7?  I wasn't able to reproduce this until I switched to a CentOS 8 Docker image, since that's where they seem to have replaced `iptables` with `iptables-nft`.  Regardless, we should be able to figure out the new syntax.

Comment: `centos:latest` {pokes self in eye with sharp pencil}.  I'll go back to 7.   Since 8 is EOL I can't use it, anyway.

Comment: @CAB Cool - That should take care of it from what I'm seeing, but I guess I still need to learn nftables syntax, since pretty much all distros are switching to it.

Comment: Thanks!  Here's a great post that covers some practical use of network namespaces: https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Just ponting out that it is no longer the case that WSL2 is Win11 only. That restriction was removed almost a year ago. Perhaps worth an update to the answer? - which by the way I wish I'd known about when you posted it - excellent stuff.

Comment: @JayM Updated - Thanks.  I'm closing in on somewhere 1,000 WSL answers here on the various SE sites, so it's become practically impossible to keep all of my answers up to date as WSL has changed.  I tend to re-read them quickly when someone upvotes or comments and try to fix them, so yes, definitely appreciate the heads-up!  Let me know if you see any others that need an update.  You can even make the edit yourself if you feel confident about it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

WSL 2 distributions all reside in the same network namespace.

You may or may not be familiar with Docker. Internally, WSL 2 works in a very similar way. WSL 2 runs in a virtual machine, on a real Linux kernel. All WSL distributions share the same virtual machine. This works by using different *containers* for each. They are isolated in various regards: each distribution has a different view on process IDs and the filesystem. They do share the same view on network interfaces.

You cannot make them have different IP addresses. It also is (mostly) irrelevant, because you can only tell the difference on your local machine. Outside, they are *NAT*ed to your PC's IP address.

Comment: Ah! I was thinking along the lines of VBox VM's. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: I think this is different from Docker. In Docker, every container has its own internal IP address. It is very important because you need to be able to communicate among containers.