# Is it possible to start "remote" VSCode to a wsl distro using a specific network namespace?

Tags: networking, visual-studio-code, wsl2

Setting up a namespace as described in the accepted answer here:
[WSL2 two separate Centos distributions have same eth0 inet address](https://superuser.com/questions/1715273/wsl2-two-separate-centos-distributions-have-same-eth0-inet-address)

Would it be possible to start a VSCode session in a wsl distribution such that it will use a network namespace?

I launch VSCode from command line like this:

code --new-window --file-uri vscode-remote://wsl%2b/home//myproj.code-workspace

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? That answer is using a network namespace to give each distro a separate IP address. VSCode would only care about that if you were connecting to WSL via ssh or something. For the example command line, you would just add the distro's name, like `code --file-uri vscode-remote://wsl+Ubuntu/home/myproj.code-workspace`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for the response. I doesn't necessarily have to do with the VSCode execution but more about the other services running within each distro. I would like to have the ability to start multiple distros by launching VSCode (which I can do) but have each instance "isolated" by IP. Each contains multiple "servers" bound addresses using identical port numbers. I think it can be done, I'd just like to have some automation behind it such that once I launch VSCode for that distro/workspace things will setup automatically regardless of the state of other distros. If thank makes sense.

Comment: Is your question just how to start multiple wsl distros? You could run `wsl.exe -d [distro] --headless` for each one to start it without entering into its console for example (`wsl.exe -t [distro]` to end it). Then launch `code` into your workspace as usual. Bundle it into a single script to automate?

Comment: It not really about starting the distros, its the process in the distros that start when VSCode is launched. It seem when VSCode starts a session in a wsl distro there are like 6-7 processes that start on the distro (ps -auxf shows) most with the parent of <path_removed>/vscode/data/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.79.5/scripts/wslServer.sh. I would like all of these processes to be started in the network namespace I create (i.e. ip netns exec vnet1 <path_removed>/wslServer.sh). There are a couple other processes that have the /init parent but I don't know if it's important for those.

Comment: Can you add some more specific examples of what you want to end up with/why? VSCode already has built-in multi-distro support via vscode command `Remote-WSL: New Window using Distro` which will launch those services. Are you trying to connect to the instance's `wslServer` service from some other software?

Comment: What I would like to see is when I start VSCode using this command : `code --file-uri vscode-remote://wsl+Ubuntu/home/myproj.code-workspace` and when in the VSCode application start the terminal (menu->terminal->new terminal) that I am placed into the network name space I created such I see `(lawson) landmark ->hostname -I
10.0.0.1 
` not `(lawson) landmark ->hostname -I
172.28.24.212 172.28.24.214 10.0.0.253 172.17.0.1 
` like have it running in the network namespace. I can do it, it's just not convenient for my users. Its not easy to describe in the comments because of formatting